Laravel api-platform integration - auth error
I'm trying to use the new Laravel api-platform integration
I have a working jetstream / sanctum app, running on laravel herd with this config:
.env
APP_URL=https://api.immo.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=api.immo.test
SESSION_DOMAIN=.immo.test

config/api-platform.php
'defaults' => [
    'route_prefix' => '/api',
    'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum'],
],

app\Models\Property
#[ApiResource]
class Property extends Model

The OpenApi Documentation works great (called with)
https://api.immo.test/api/

But when I want to call a resource like /api/properties, I always get an authenticate error (part of the exception trace), and check in laravel telescope it looks like the user could not be recognized. What am I missing?
{
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "/Volumes/Work/Code/imapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
      "line": 88,
      "function": "unauthenticated",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/Volumes/Work/Code/imapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
      "line": 62,
      "function": "authenticate",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/Volumes/Work/Code/imapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/Volumes/Work/Code/imapi/vendor/api-platform/laravel/ApiPlatformMiddleware.php",
      "line": 47,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "type": "/errors/401",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthenticated."
}

My other app routes with sanctum are working, ex:
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user', fn () => request()->user());
});

